# Many to Many Spring MVC mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring

Good day everyone
I’m trying to create a relationship for the entities Shelter and Owner, **many to many**, but a mistake is climbing, I do not understand what's the matter

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @DynamicUpdate
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "owner")
    public class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idOwner;

    private String name;

    private String address;

    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "owner_shelter",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "owner")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "shelter")}
    )
    private Set<Shelter> shelterOwner;
}
```

--

```
@Data
@DynamicUpdate
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "shelter")
    public class Shelter {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        private String name;
        private String address;
        private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shelter")
    private Set<Owner> sheltersOwner;
}
```

and the error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: ru.itis.springbootdemo.models.Owner.shelter in ru.itis.springbootdemo.models.Shelter.sheltersOwner**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message is explicit , this is not correct

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shelter")
 private Set<Owner> sheltersOwner;
```

should be

```java
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "shelterOwner")
 private Set<Owner> sheltersOwner;
```

`mappedBy` references the other side attribute name and in your code it is not correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

problem is field name of the shelter in `Owner` class, it must be `private Set<Shelter> shelter;` 
not `private Set<Shelter> shelterOwner;`